# Unable to use redirected std::cout in Catch2

Tags: c++, catch2

I'm writing test for my class using Catch2 (single header file version `catch.hpp`). My class output some text into `std::cout`, and I cannot change this behavior. I need to retrieve output from `std::cout` for comparison. To do this, I redirect `std::cout` into `std::ostringstream` like this:

```
    auto stdoutBuffer = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
```

Now I am able to compare content of `oss` with `oss.str()`.
But when some `REQUIRE()` fails, I get an exception `Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` in `TestRegistry` catch class

However, if all the checks were successful, when no assertion was failed, then no exception will be thrown

Catch allows to use `CATCH_CONFIG_NOSTDOUT` to override the functions `cout()`, `cerr()` and `clog()`. But examples that I have seen for their implementation (like this https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/examples/231-Cfg-OutputStreams.cpp) look superfluous for the original problem. Are there any other ways to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from `avred` is good, but it is a good practice to provide helper function which will make this easier to use. This will also make test easier to read.

```cpp
#include "catch2/catch_all.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo";
}

class AutoRestoreRdbuf {
    std::ostream& out;
    std::streambuf* old;

public:
    ~AutoRestoreRdbuf()
    {
        out.rdbuf(old);
    }
    AutoRestoreRdbuf(const AutoRestoreRdbuf&) = delete;
    AutoRestoreRdbuf(AutoRestoreRdbuf&&) = delete;

    AutoRestoreRdbuf(std::ostream& out)
        : out { out }
        , old { out.rdbuf() }
    {
    }
};

std::string stringWrittentToStream(std::function<void()> f, std::ostream& out = std::cout)
{
    AutoRestoreRdbuf restore { std::cout };
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
    f();
    return oss.str();
}

TEST_CASE("Foo")
{
    auto s = stringWrittentToStream(&foo);
    REQUIRE(s == "foo1");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3877s5K56

Answer (score 3):

Before calling REQUIRE, make sure you are restoring the state of the cout again.

```
auto stdoutBuffer = std::cout.rdbuf();
std::ostringstream oss;
std::cout.rdbuf(oss.rdbuf());
testcode();
std::cout.rdbuf(stdoutBuffer);
REQUIRE(oss.str() == "Foobar");
```

Otherwise rdbuf points to a local variable, that may already have been deallocated.

A not so beautiful variant would be making oss a global variable.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/6afxr4vW8